# Prevent hyperlinks from opening in new tab/window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to prevent the links in my website from opening in a new tab. I have changed the attribute to `_self`, but it doesn't work and I don't know what else to do. Please take a look at my code below and tell me how to fix it. If you don't understand what I'm asking for, feel free to ask me any question and I will explain better.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html class="" lang="en"><head><!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '131624710840337'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=131624710840337&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><!-- Google Tag Manager --><script src="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/558811507626827.js" async=""></script><script async="" src="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/fbevents.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/mixpanel-2-latest.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/analytics.js"></script><script async="" src="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/gtm.js"></script><script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-N9PX6N');</script><!-- End Google Tag Manager --><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"><title>@ </title><meta name="description" content=""><link rel="canonical" href="https://"><meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"><meta property="og:type" content="website"><meta property="og:title" content="@Realestateconnect | Messenger"><meta property="og:description" content="Linktree. Make your Instagram Bio Link do more."><meta property="og:url" content="https://"><meta property="og:site_name" content="Linktree"><meta property="og:image" content="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/24178217_828350774024081_5553302974681317376_n.jpg"><meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"><meta name="twitter:description" content="Linktree. Make your Instagram Bio Link do more."><meta name="twitter:title" content="@Realestateconnect | Linktree"><meta name="twitter:domain" content="Linktree"><meta name="twitter:image" content="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/24178217_828350774024081_5553302974681317376_n.jpg"><!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"><![endif]--><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://linktr.ee/favicon.ico"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://linktr.ee/favicon.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="https://linktr.ee/apple-icon-57x57.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="https://linktr.ee/apple-icon-60x60.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="https://linktr.ee/apple-icon-72x72.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://linktr.ee/apple-icon-76x76.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="https://linktr.ee/apple-icon-114x114.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://linktr.ee/apple-icon-120x120.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="https://linktr.ee/apple-icon-144x144.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://linktr.ee/apple-icon-152x152.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="https://linktr.ee/apple-icon-180x180.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="https://linktr.ee/android-icon-192x192.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="https://linktr.ee/favicon-32x32.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="https://linktr.ee/favicon-96x96.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="https://linktr.ee/favicon-16x16.png"><link rel="manifest" href="https://linktr.ee/manifest.json"><meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff"><meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png"><meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"><script src="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>(function(H){H.className=H.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script><script type="text/javascript" src="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/sdk.js"></script><link href="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/styles.css"><!-- start Mixpanel --><script type="text/javascript">(function(e,b){if(!b.__SV){var a,f,i,g;window.mixpanel=b;b._i=[];b.init=function(a,e,d){function f(b,h){var a=h.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],h=a[1]);b[h]=function(){b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var c=b;"undefined"!==typeof d?c=b[d]=[]:d="mixpanel";c.people=c.people||[];c.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==d&&(a+="."+d);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};c.people.toString=function(){return c.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};i="disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");for(g=0;g<i.length;g++)f(c,i[g]);b._i.push([a,e,d])};b.__SV=1.2;a=e.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="undefined"!==typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL?MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL:"file:"===e.location.protocol&&"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//)?"https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js":"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js";f=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];f.parentNode.insertBefore(a,f)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);mixpanel.init("c43d8c74fd8875191d029f4b00b2e036");</script><!-- end Mixpanel --><style type="text/css">.fb_hidden{position:absolute;top:-10000px;z-index:10001}.fb_reposition{overflow:hidden;position:relative}.fb_invisible{display:none}.fb_reset{background:none;border:0;border-spacing:0;color:#000;cursor:auto;direction:ltr;font-family:"lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:normal;line-height:1;margin:0;overflow:visible;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;text-indent:0;text-shadow:none;text-transform:none;visibility:visible;white-space:normal;word-spacing:normal}.fb_reset>div{overflow:hidden}.fb_link img{border:none}@keyframes fb_transform{from{opacity:0;transform:scale(.95)}to{opacity:1;transform:scale(1)}}.fb_animate{animation:fb_transform .3s forwards}
.fb_dialog{background:rgba(82, 82, 82, .7);position:absolute;top:-10000px;z-index:10001}.fb_reset .fb_dialog_legacy{overflow:visible}.fb_dialog_advanced{padding:10px;-moz-border-radius:8px;-webkit-border-radius:8px;border-radius:8px}.fb_dialog_content{background:#fff;color:#333}.fb_dialog_close_icon{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;cursor:pointer;display:block;height:15px;position:absolute;right:18px;top:17px;width:15px}.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_icon{top:5px;left:5px;right:auto}.fb_dialog_padding{background-color:transparent;position:absolute;width:1px;z-index:-1}.fb_dialog_close_icon:hover{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -15px transparent}.fb_dialog_close_icon:active{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -30px transparent}.fb_dialog_loader{background-color:#f6f7f9;border:1px solid #606060;font-size:24px;padding:20px}.fb_dialog_top_left,.fb_dialog_top_right,.fb_dialog_bottom_left,.fb_dialog_bottom_right{height:10px;width:10px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute}.fb_dialog_top_left{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 0;left:-10px;top:-10px}.fb_dialog_top_right{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 -10px;right:-10px;top:-10px}.fb_dialog_bottom_left{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 -20px;bottom:-10px;left:-10px}.fb_dialog_bottom_right{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 -30px;right:-10px;bottom:-10px}.fb_dialog_vert_left,.fb_dialog_vert_right,.fb_dialog_horiz_top,.fb_dialog_horiz_bottom{position:absolute;background:#525252;filter:alpha(opacity=70);opacity:.7}.fb_dialog_vert_left,.fb_dialog_vert_right{width:10px;height:100%}.fb_dialog_vert_left{margin-left:-10px}.fb_dialog_vert_right{right:0;margin-right:-10px}.fb_dialog_horiz_top,.fb_dialog_horiz_bottom{width:100%;height:10px}.fb_dialog_horiz_top{margin-top:-10px}.fb_dialog_horiz_bottom{bottom:0;margin-bottom:-10px}.fb_dialog_iframe{line-height:0}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_title{background:#6d84b4;border:1px solid #365899;color:#fff;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;margin:0}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_title>span{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yd/r/Cou7n-nqK52.gif) no-repeat 5px 50%;float:left;padding:5px 0 7px 26px}body.fb_hidden{-webkit-transform:none;height:100%;margin:0;overflow:visible;position:absolute;top:-10000px;left:0;width:100%}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ya/r/3rhSv5V8j3o.gif) white no-repeat 50% 50%;min-height:100%;min-width:100%;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;z-index:10001}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading.centered{width:auto;height:auto;min-height:initial;min-width:initial;background:none}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading.centered #fb_dialog_loader_spinner{width:100%}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading.centered .fb_dialog_content{background:none}.loading.centered #fb_dialog_loader_close{color:#fff;display:block;padding-top:20px;clear:both;font-size:18px}#fb-root #fb_dialog_ipad_overlay{background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;top:0;width:100%;min-height:100%;z-index:10000}#fb-root #fb_dialog_ipad_overlay.hidden{display:none}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading iframe{visibility:hidden}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header{-webkit-box-shadow:white 0 1px 1px -1px inset;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#738ABA), to(#2C4987));border-bottom:1px solid;border-color:#1d4088;color:#fff;font:14px Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;text-overflow:ellipsis;text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0;vertical-align:middle;white-space:nowrap}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header table{-webkit-font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased;height:43px;width:100%}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header td.header_left{font-size:12px;padding-left:5px;vertical-align:middle;width:60px}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header td.header_right{font-size:12px;padding-right:5px;vertical-align:middle;width:60px}.fb_dialog_content .touchable_button{background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#4966A6), color-stop(.5, #355492), to(#2A4887));border:1px solid #29487d;-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, .117188) 0 1px 1px inset, rgba(255, 255, 255, .167969) 0 1px 0;display:inline-block;margin-top:3px;max-width:85px;line-height:18px;padding:4px 12px;position:relative}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header .touchable_button input{border:none;background:none;color:#fff;font:12px Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;margin:2px -12px;padding:2px 6px 3px 6px;text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header .header_center{color:#fff;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;line-height:18px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_content{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y9/r/jKEcVPZFk-2.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;border:1px solid #555;border-bottom:0;border-top:0;height:150px}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_footer{background:#f6f7f9;border:1px solid #555;border-top-color:#ccc;height:40px}#fb_dialog_loader_close{float:left}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_button{text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_icon{visibility:hidden}#fb_dialog_loader_spinner{animation:rotateSpinner 1.2s linear infinite;background-color:transparent;background-image:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yD/r/t-wz8gw1xG1.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:50% 50%;height:24px;width:24px}@keyframes rotateSpinner{0%{transform:rotate(0deg)}100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}
.fb_iframe_widget{display:inline-block;position:relative}.fb_iframe_widget span{display:inline-block;position:relative;text-align:justify}.fb_iframe_widget iframe{position:absolute}.fb_iframe_widget_fluid_desktop,.fb_iframe_widget_fluid_desktop span,.fb_iframe_widget_fluid_desktop iframe{max-width:100%}.fb_iframe_widget_fluid_desktop iframe{min-width:220px;position:relative}.fb_iframe_widget_lift{z-index:1}.fb_hide_iframes iframe{position:relative;left:-10000px}.fb_iframe_widget_loader{position:relative;display:inline-block}.fb_iframe_widget_fluid{display:inline}.fb_iframe_widget_fluid span{width:100%}.fb_iframe_widget_loader iframe{min-height:32px;z-index:2;zoom:1}.fb_iframe_widget_loader .FB_Loader{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y9/r/jKEcVPZFk-2.gif) no-repeat;height:32px;width:32px;margin-left:-16px;position:absolute;left:50%;z-index:4}
.fb_invisible_flow{display:inherit;height:0;overflow-x:hidden;width:0}.fb_mobile_overlay_active{height:100%;overflow:hidden;position:fixed;width:100%}.fb_shrink_active{opacity:1;transform:scale(1, 1);transition-duration:200ms;transition-timing-function:ease-out}.fb_shrink_active:active{opacity:.5;transform:scale(.75, .75)}</style></head><head>
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '131624710840337'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=131624710840337&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
</head>
<script>fbq('track', '<EVENT_NAME>');</script>
<body class="service theme colourway-moon video no-touch browser-firefox" data-account=""><!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) --><noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-N9PX6N"
  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript><!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) --><div class="service"><header class="service-header"><div class="login"><div class="inner"><a href="https://linktr.ee/admin"><img class="img-circle" src="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/24178217_828350774024081_5553302974681317376_n.jpg"></a></div></div></header><section class="main"><div class="container service-container"><div class="user-area"><div class="text-xs-center"><img class="user-img img-circle" src="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/24178217_828350774024081_5553302974681317376_n.jpg"><h3><a class="user-name btn">

                 <p></p>
                 <p></p>
               </a></h3></div></div><div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_self"> Abia State</a></div></div></div></div><div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> Adamawa State</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="abuja.html" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_parent"> Abuja State</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k"  class="btn btn-link" >  Anambra State</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> Akwa Ibom State </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> Bauchi State </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> Bayelsa State</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> Benue State </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> Borno State </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> CROSS RIVER STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> DELTA STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> EBONYI STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> EDO STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> EKITI STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> ENUGU STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> GOMBE STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> IMO STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank">JIGAWA STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> KADUNA STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> KANO STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> KASTINA STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> KEBBI STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> KOGI STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> KWARA STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> LAGOS STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> NASSARAWA STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> NIGER STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> OGUN STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> ONDO STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> OSUN STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> OYO STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> PLATEAU STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> RIVERS STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank">SOKOTO STATE </a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> TARABA STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> YOBE STATE</a></div></div></div></div>
               <div class="links"><div><div><div class="link"><a href="k" data-url="k" class="btn btn-link" target="_blank"> ZAMFARA STATE </a></div></div></div></div>

               </div></section><section class="service-footer"><div class="service-logo-wrap"><h1><a href="k">
    Realestateconnecte
    <span class="logo"></span></a></h1></div></section></div><script src="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/vendor.js"></script><script src="@mobilealertservices%20_%20Linktree_files/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="">!function(b,e,f,g,a,c,d){b.fbq||(a=b.fbq=function(){a.callMethod?a.callMethod.apply(a,arguments):a.queue.push(arguments)},b._fbq||(b._fbq=a),a.push=a,a.loaded=!0,a.version="2.0",a.queue=[],c=e.createElement(f),c.async=!0,c.src=g,d=e.getElementsByTagName(f)[0],d.parentNode.insertBefore(c,d))}(window,document,"script","https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js");fbq("init","558811507626827");fbq("track","PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=558811507626827&amp;ev=PageView&amp;noscript=1"></noscript>
<div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset"><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div></div></div></div><script type="text/javascript" id="">fbq("track","linkClick");</script>
</body></html
```

Comment: You should post this as an [mcve]. Posting minimized code full of other irrelevant details isn't very helpful.

Comment: okay ,i will do that ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to remove `target="_blank"` from your links. Before:

```
<a target="_blank">Link</a>
```

After:

```
<a>Link</a>
```

Also, you don't need `target="_self"` or `"target="_parent"` for this task. You could remove them too.

**Some additional information**

From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp):

> `<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|`*framename*`">`
>
> - `_blank` - Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
> - `_self` - Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
> - `_parent` - Opens the linked document in the parent frame
> - `_top` - Opens the linked document in the full body of the window
> - *framename* - Load in a named frame

So, `<a>Link</a>` and `<a target="_self">Link</a>` works identically.

Comment: i just removed target="_blank" but it didn't work ,it is opened a new tab .

Comment: @MascotAyere Very strange. It works for me - exactly as it should. I made example for you - just copy it: http://jsfiddle.net/vqbnthwo

Comment: thank you very much for your help ,i noticed it worked perfectly in http://jsfiddle.net/ but it is still opening a new tab in my browser ,i guess it should be my browser settings ,but it is okay ,since it worked for you ,i know it will work for others .i can use it now for my project .thanks again

Comment: @MascotAyere I suggest to test it. Create a blank HTML file on your desktop and copy this code into this blank file. Then launch this file in your browser. In this case, if you see the error - then the problem is in your browser and you don't need to worry about users. But if you DON'T see the error - then your browser works correctly and the actual problem is probably in configuration of your web server and so, you need to fix it somehow (it could be asked at https://serverfault.com/). Also, don't forgot to click the check mark on the left side of my answer.

Comment: i didn't see the error .This means the error is from my web server.I will ask them at serverfault.com , i didn't see the left mark you are talking about ,please show me screen shot .Thanks

Comment: I have a problem with my css ,please check it out and see if you can fix it ,here is where i asked the question .Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583946/my-page-is-not-completely-responsive

Comment: Attached files works for me. What problem did you have? Everything looks responive. And please, when you ask questions - align you code properly and write you text properly. Why someone should fix this mess for you?

Comment: okay ,noted .I will align the code properly next time .This is what i mean when i say my page is not  completely responsive .Take a look at the text in  this image http://prntscr.com/kcjxuu  ,you can see the full text ,but for this mobile view ,http://prntscr.com/kcjy6p  part of the text is cut off. I want all the text to show in the mobile view too